# Clicking a series of buttons to satisfy a condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I have four buttons at present i'm getting alert when all the buttons are pressed but what i want is when we press a combination of buttons like button1 and button 3 or button1 and button2 or button3 and button4 alert should be displayed not when all buttons are clicked

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Display</title>

</head>
<body>
<center>
</br></br></br></br></br></br>
<button id="button1" class="tictac" type="button" onclick="button1check()">button1</button>
<button id="button2"  type="button" onclick="button2check()">button2</button></br></br>
<button id="button3"  type="button" onclick="button3check()">button3</button>
<button id="button4" class="tictac" type="button" onclick="button4check()">button4</button>
</center>

<script type="text/javascript">
button1clicked = 0;
button2clicked = 0;
button3clicked = 0;
button4clicked = 0;

function button1check() {



  button1clicked = 1;  


   if (button1clicked == 1 && button2clicked == 1 && button3clicked == 1 && button4clicked == 1 ) {
    alert('you win!');
    button1clicked = 0;
    button2clicked = 0;
    button3clicked = 0;
    button4clicked = 0;

  }
}


function button2check() {

    button2clicked = 1;


   if (button1clicked == 1 && button2clicked == 1 && button3clicked == 1 && button4clicked == 1) {
    alert('you win!');
    button1clicked = 0;
    button2clicked = 0;
    button3clicked = 0;
    button4clicked = 0;

  }

}

 function button3check() {

   button3clicked = 1;


   if (button1clicked == 1 && button2clicked == 1 && button3clicked == 1 && button4clicked == 1) {
    alert('you win!');
    button1clicked = 0;
    button2clicked = 0;
    button3clicked = 0;
    button4clicked = 0;
  }
}


  function button4check() {

  button4clicked = 1;

  if (button1clicked == 1 && button2clicked == 1 && button3clicked == 1 && button4clicked == 1 ) {
    alert('you win!');
    button1clicked = 0;
    button2clicked = 0;
    button3clicked = 0;
    button4clicked = 0;
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working your example, however, your code is also working.

```js
var btns = [0,0,0,0];

function checkButtons() {
  if (btns[0] == 1 && btns[1] == 1 && btns[2] == 1 && btns[3] == 1) {
    alert('You win!');
    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
      btns[i] = 0;
    }
  }
}

function btnClick(n) {
  btns[n - 1] = 1;
  checkButtons();
}
```

```html
<center>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  <button onclick="btnClick(1)">button1</button>
  <button onclick="btnClick(2)">button2</button>
  </br>
  </br>
  <button onclick="btnClick(3)">button3</button>
  <button onclick="btnClick(4)">button4</button>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose a different approach. With below code, you can set a winning combination in the `winner` array. If the clickcount is equal to the button count and the winning combination has not been clicked, the game is reset.

```js
let winner = [[1, 3], [2,4]];
let clicked = [];

let btns = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("button"));
btns.forEach(b => {
  b.addEventListener('click', function(el) {
    let number = el.target.id.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
    clicked.push(number);
    if (winner.some(w => w.sort().join("") === clicked.sort().join(''))) {
      alert("You're a winner");
      clicked = [];
    } else if (clicked.length === btns.length) {
      clicked = [];
      alert("Nah!");
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<button id="button1" class="tictac" type="button">button1</button>
<button id="button2" type="button">button2</button>
<button id="button3" type="button">button3</button>
<button id="button4" class="tictac" type="button">button4</button>
```

Comment: can we set multiple arrays like an array for one combination and another for another combination.

Comment: Edited the answer so that it's possible @vamshi